# Parcelable Issues When Obfuscating With Proguard

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, proguard, parcelable

My app works fine before obfuscation but when I enable proguard I get the following error:

```
2013-05-02 13:43:58.772 E 30138/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "0.20"
    at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:125)
    at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:362)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:353)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:319)
    at com.sourcetone.data.model.Station.long getId()(SourceFile:195)
    at com.sourcetone.STStationListFragment.void deleteStation(com.sourcetone.data.model.Station)(SourceFile:298)
    at com.sourcetone.STStationListFragment.void access$4(com.sourcetone.STStationListFragment,com.sourcetone.data.model.Station)(SourceFile:293)
    at com.sourcetone.STStationListFragment$ArrayListAdapter$1.void onClick(android.view.View)(SourceFile:274)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3528)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14217)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4482)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

2013-05-02 13:43:58.803 W 472/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.sourcetone/.STMainActivity
```

My proguard config has the following:

```
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

So Parcelable should be keep right? The Invalid Long that it's throwing is actually another part of my request so it's reading the wrong number. Do I have to keep my HttpResponse class as well? What else could it be?

Comment: It depends on how you parse your request. Which reflective libraries are you using? Gson, Jackson?

Answer (score 6):

```
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Doesn't keep all the content of your class intact, it just keeps the classname and the CREATOR method.

Try to keep the fields too in your Parcelable class, add something like :

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
 public <fields>;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

It will just keep the class name and the CREATOR.

You should change it to

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}
```

Default android rules includes the above instruction, and will be applied to your project too, if you leave the default generated gradle definition in place:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```